# Duty free allowance for rice and beans in Switzerland

Tags: customs-and-immigration, food-and-drink, switzerland, duty-free

We are immigrating to switzerland and we prefer bringing some foods for at least beginning days in switzerland. Could you please help me to know how much rice and beans is allowded to bring with ourselves.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but why would you do that even if you're arriving on a Sunday? Go out, find a bakery, buy some fresh bread rolls. You'll have to do that sooner or later. Some things are rather expensive in Switzerland, but bringing things in airline luggage has to be more expensive.

Comment: Surely rice and beans are both widely available in Switzerland?

Comment: This question is about moving to Switzerland, so you should ask on Expatriates SE instead: https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Unless you're proposing that the immigration aspect makes a difference to the question, I see no reason to close.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I am not just proposing that. As in probably most countries, the Swiss customs regulations are completely different if you are moving there and therefore bring your belongings with you (which includes household supplies like food), or if you are temporary visiting as a tourist.

Answer (score 1):

tax free limit in Switzerland is CHF 300 per person (last time I went at least), as long as you stay below that ride and beans are ok to bring as long as they are packed in original packages etc

Best pack this in your checked in luggage as the airline might object to it being in your Carry on

And don’t forget to declare it on arrival even though you are below the tax limit

Comment: It'd be great if you could add some references to your answer. Where in the world do airlines inspect the contents of carry-on luggage? And why should they object to rice and beans when these don't present any risk to flight safety?

Comment: @TooTea Agreed. Weight is the only problem I can imagine, assuming dried beans.

Comment: @TooTea China for one does it randomly, Vietnam, even Sweden, and it’s not about the safety as such but more about weight

Comment: Here, everything is wrong. The CHF 300 limit applies for goods you have bought abroad and bring back with you as a resident of Switzerland, or for goods you bring to Switzerland as a visitor and intend to leave there. The limit is not relevant when moving to Switzerland, in which case completely different rules apply. There is also absolutely no reason not to bring rice or beans in carry-on luggage and no requirements to declare it on arrival.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Have you support or a citation for the assertion that property (here, food) being brought by an immigrant need not be declared to Customs?